# How to make a picturebox transparent over 2 labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a picturebox transparent over 2 labels. I have [this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zvOT.jpg). I want it to appear over "Yes" and "No", but while me able to see "Yes" and "No" integrally, not croped like that.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Overlapping controls cannot be transparent, only nested ones can. Often painting and drawing the content is the best solution.

Comment: I'm using Winforms

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the Winform designer, you can right click a control and select 'Bring to Front' or 'Send to Back' from the context menu to change the control's 'z-order.'

Comment: If I 'send to back' the 'X', there will be the corners from answer's labels over it, so the problem is the same.

Comment: @AdelinRau Just to set background transparent for labels

Comment: I tried to make labels's back color transparent but it won't work. ( `label4.BackColor = Color.Transparent` )

Comment: It works for me : http://c2n.me/3F7hloX.png, you do something wrong